# like on post just as facebook

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listviewitem

- I have listivew and fill listview from json response
- In adapter class i have a button for like
- In my json response i m getting likestatus for post,i.e when i send my user-id it gives me all post, and in json response for particular post i am getting likestatus i.e "yes" or "no"
- what i have done :

adapter class :

```
ivPostLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                View tempView = (View) v.getTag(R.integer.btnplusview);
                pos = (Integer) v.getTag(R.integer.btnpluspos);
                ivPostLike = (ImageView) tempView.findViewById(R.id.ivPostLike);
                like_feed = String.valueOf(pos);

                Log.e("posssstre", post_id);

                if (likeStatus.equals(null))
                {
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    if (likeStatus.equals("yes"))
                    {
                        like = "no";
                        ivPostLike.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.icon_heart);
                    }

                    else {
                        like = "yes";
                        ivPostLike.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heartlike);
                    }
                }

                likePost(like);

            }
        });
        tvPostDetail.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

        return itemView;
    }
```

Json response :

```
"status": true,
    "message": "Successfully Get user list data",
    "data": [
        {
            "user_id": "50",
            "post_id": "61",
            "text": "Hellooo ,, Testing"
            "status": [
                {
                    "likestatus": "yes"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "user_id": "50",
            "post_id": "50",
            "text": "Hello",         
            "status": [
                {
                    "likestatus": "yes"
                }
            ]
        }
]
}
```

- I am not getting particular item on click , i.e if i click on post no 61 i am getting like on post no 50
- I am getting wrong id on click, position is different from what i click

Comment: i think you should check from adapter which value you are getting according to position, its user_id or post_id.

Comment: getting same value everytime

Comment: gettting same postid everytime

Comment: deal done. solved....

Comment: ok getting postid than work with postid and update as u can